# apache force if url has specific pattern redirect to https

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect, https

How can I force `Apache` if `URI` start with "admin-" pattern or contain "admin/user/login" redirect to https of the same uri.

For example:

If the URI is :

```
http://examplesite.com/admin-2dns24dw
```

Redirect to :

```
https://examplesite.com/admin-2dns24dw
```

And if the URI is :

```
http://examplesite.com/en/admin/user/login/msg
```

redirect to :

```
https://examplesite.com/en/admin/user/login/msg
```

And if any https `URI` that hasn't any of this patterns should be redirect to http of same `URL`.

For example:

If the URI is :

```
https://examplesite.com/fa/dashboard
```

Redirect to :

```
http://examplesite.com/fa/dashboard
```

**  UPDATE **

I tried:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} admin-|admin/users/login [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(my) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

but it didn't worked.

whats the problem?

Comment: Don't use "THE_REQUEST", it's not unescaped. Why does your rewrite rule start with "my"??

Comment: I don't know,a guy suggested it to me. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This will rewrite any URL that matches the pattern in the `RewriteRule` to the same URL over HTTPS.

Comment: can you express examples according to my specific patterns?

Comment: No, that's your work.

Comment: your answer is irrelevant to my question

Comment: @ArashMousavi The answer is absolutely relevant, as is the question this has been marked as a duplicate of. [Stack Exchange is not here to do your job for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question).

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: that's your work - lol

Answer (score 1):

You can try [mod_alias - Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) Redirect Directive.

```
Example:

Redirect /service http://foo2.example.com/service
```

*** UPDATE ***

```
Redirect /admin-2dns24dw https://examplesite.com/fa/dashboard
```

Comment: can you express examples according to my examples?

Comment: I questioned about any URL that start with "admin-", but your example is static.

Comment: and also I want redirect any url with https without these two pattern redirect to http.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: Using mod_alias like this can result in a redirect loop. You really should mention that, and how to avoid it.

Comment: @ArashMousavi 1) make sure that mod_rewrite isn't commented out 2) look in your logs to see where the problem is, also if you need to use regex pattern then you should use mod_rewrite, if it's simple redirect then mod_alias is better.